# Stage not working

Tags: ros, simulation, roomba, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/lse_roomba_toolbox/Tutorials/Simulating%20a%20Roomba%20on%20Stage

When I enter this command,
rosrun stage stageros roomba_isr_floor0.world

it gives this error

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named stageros below /opt/ros/hydro/share/stage

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192600/stage-not-working/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on 2015-01-12**:
I had same problem bro. Did you solve that error?

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2015-07-29**:
Does anyone knows how to solve this? I'm having the same error here... I'm trying to run stage with a simple command:
$  rosrun stage_ros stageros ./map01_Room.world
But I get this error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named stageros below /opt/ros/indigo/share/stage_ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've got the package name wrong, it's `stage_ros` not `stageros` and the executable name is `stageros` not `stage_ros` (confusing I know). When I run that command:

```
$ rosrun stage stage_ros roomba_isr_floor0.world
```

On my Ubuntu 12.04.5 Hydro install I get an error that it cannot find the world file (expected) but if does find and run `stageros`:

```
william@ubuntu:~$ rosrun stage_ros stageros roomba_isr_floor0.world
[FATAL] [1438216243.460273767]: The world file roomba_isr_floor0.world does not exist.
 [Loading roomba_isr_floor0.world]err: unable to open world file roomba_isr_floor0.world : No such file or directory (/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-stage-4.1.1-6precise-20141231-2201/libstage/worldfile.cc Load)

Stage: User closed window
```

It looks like that tutorial needs to be updated. If you figure out what it should be please feel free to update the tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
Update to `<node pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros"`  . Related:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/200779/question-about-tutorial-introduction-to-stage-controllers-stageros-problem/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/214157/how-do-i-install-stage-and-stage_ros/